# Handle submit event of form with outer button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have small issue with native html form.
I want to submit form with outer button, as you can see on attached fiddle link. But, the same time I need to prevent generating xhr.request. So, in my case I need handle submit.event occurring on form.
I see it if submit form by inner button, but can not handle if invoke .submit() event straightforward by outer button. Does somebody has recipe?
Thank a lot for feedbacks :)

```js
var formElem = document.querySelector('#form');
var innerButtonElem = document.querySelector('#innerButton');
var outerButtonElem = document.querySelector('#outerButton');

formElem.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
 console.log('formElem', event);
})

innerButton.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
 console.log('innerButton submit', event);
})

innerButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 console.log('innerButton click', event);
})

outerButtonElem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 console.log('outerButton', event);
  formElem.submit();
})
```

```css
#innerButton {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Test form</p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="second input">
  <button id="innerButton" type="submit">Inner button</button>
</form>
<button id="outerButton">Outer button</button>
```

Comment: I think that would be hard. You should wrap submit `button` inside `form` instead. That would be best option.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware how to solve this issue in general, but in this case I need  have a outer button for submit form. In real life it is Angular 5 project and various components, I made example simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `form` attribute on the `<button>` to link it to your `<form>` by `id`

```
<button id="outerButton" form="form" type="submit">Outer button</button>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form

Comment: Thanks a lot, excellent)                                                                                                  It is pity, but it is not support IE 11 :(                                         https://caniuse.com/#search=button

Answer (score 1):

You might use `label` element as outer button:

```js
var formElem = document.querySelector('#form');

formElem.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('formElem', event.type);
})
```

```css
#submit {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:1em 0; padding:0 1em;
  line-height:1.5;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #eee
}
```

```html
<p>Test form</p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="second input">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<label for="submit">Outer button</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you, now we are using this solution, but I don't want to create extra buttons or inputs. But thanks)

Comment: @Alex, happy to help! BTW, maybe you can use inner button and adjust its position with CSS?

Comment: @Very    not in real life it is big project on Angular 5, and nested form with outer button. We faced with problem how can we check validators, submit form if it is ok, or show errors and prevent refresh page && creating xhr request if it is not valid. In the end chose your variant. It works nice for half a year, but I don't give up searching a better solution :). Position with CSS...not for production :) But thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the outer button click on the inner button when clicked.

```css
#innerButton {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Test form</p>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="first input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="second input">
  <button id="innerButton" type="submit">Inner button</button>
</form>
<button id="outerButton">Outer button</button>
<script>
var formElem = document.querySelector('#form');
var innerButtonElem = document.querySelector('#innerButton');
var outerButtonElem = document.querySelector('#outerButton');

innerButtonElem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 console.log('innerButton', event.type);
});

outerButtonElem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
 console.log('outerButton', event.type);
  innerButtonElem.click();
});

formElem.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
 console.log('formElem', event.type);
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```